# GitLab Merge Request falsely only shows/uses the jobs run throught `rules` as merge permission

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have changed a few jobs in our GitLab CI pipeline to only run under certain conditions, like this:

```yaml
foo:
  stage: a
  rules:
    - exists:
        - "some/file"
    - changes:
        - "some/bla"
  script:
    - "echo 1"
```

All other jobs are implemented "normal", i.e., like this:

```yaml
bar:
  stage: a
  script:
    - "echo 2"
```

We have setup the repository like that, that Merge Requests are only allowed to be merged **if the pipeline succeeds**.
However, since this change, only the jobs that are listed through `rules` are applied to that, i.e., it looks now like this in the web interface:

[image: Merge permission ok]

and the UI would let me merge this, altough the latest "normal" jobs did not succeed at all:

[image: all jobs]

How can I enforce that **all** jobs need to succeed to mark a branch mergeable?

Comment: By default, jobs do not run on [merge request pipelines](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/merge_request_pipelines.html). Adding `rules:` to a job will cause it to run on merge request pipelines. When you have one or more jobs that run on merge request pipelines, only the MR pipeline result (not the branch pipeline) will affect the ability to merge with the 'pipeline must succeed' setting. It's an odd quirk.

Comment: Thanks, using [Switch between branch pipelines and merge request pipelines](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/workflow.html#switch-between-branch-pipelines-and-merge-request-pipelines) works as expected!
If you make this an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to run only on branch **OR** merge request is to use (on GitLab 13.8 or later)

```yaml
workflow:
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH && $CI_OPEN_MERGE_REQUESTS
      when: never
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH
```

Reference: [Switch between branch pipelines and merge request pipelines](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/workflow.html#switch-between-branch-pipelines-and-merge-request-pipelines)